# Retrieving ajax data synchronously back to calling function

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have a form featuring the google captcha code: http://code.google.com/p/cool-php-captcha.

As this captcha uses a session to store the captcha I am having difficulty retrieving the upto date variable of the session into javascript through ajax. It was working well when my ajax command was using the async: false flag but as this is being depreciated I would rather not use it.

My problem at the moment is that I am trying to use a callback function to retrieve the value but by trying to send the value back to the original function I am creating a loop between my 2 functions and can't quite figure out the best way to get what I want.

thanks for any help cheers Callum

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function getcaptchsession()
{
 $.ajax({url:'/Includes/Session.php', cache:false, type: 'GET', success:function(data, status, XHR){validate(data);}});
}

function validate(data)
{
 var session = data;
 var ok = '';
 var nameerror = '';
 var emailerror = '';
 var subjecterror = '';
 var messageerror = '';
 var contactform = document.forms.ContactForm;
 var fullname = contactform.Fullname.value;
 var emailadd = contactform.Emailadd.value;
 var subject = contactform.Subject.value;
 var message = contactform.Message.value;
 var captcha = contactform.CaptchaText.value;

getcaptchsession();

if (fullname == "")
{
 var x = document.getElementsByClassName("error");
 x[0].innerHTML = "Name field is a required field.";
 nameerror = true;
}
else if (fullname != "")
{
 if (/[^a-z\s-]/i.test(fullname))
 {
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("error");
  x[0].innerHTML = "Alphabetic characters only.";
  nameerror = true;
 }
 else
 {
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("error");
  x[0].innerHTML = "";
  nameerror = false;
 }
}

if (emailadd == "")
{
 var x = document.getElementsByClassName("error");
 x[1].innerHTML = "Email field is a required field.";
 emailerror = true;
}
else if (emailadd != "")
{
 if (/^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/.test(emailadd))
{
 var x = document.getElementsByClassName("error");
 x[1].innerHTML = "";
 emailerror = false;
}
else
{
 var x = document.getElementsByClassName("error");
 x[1].innerHTML = "Email is not a valid email address.";
 nameerror = true;
}
}

if (subject == "")
{
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("error");
x[2].innerHTML = "Subject field is a required field.";
subjecterror = true;
}
else
{
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("error");
x[2].innerHTML = "";
subjecterror = false;
}

if (message == "")
{
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("error");
x[3].innerHTML = "Message field is a required field.";
messageerror = true;
}
else
{
 var x = document.getElementsByClassName("error");
 x[3].innerHTML = "";
 messageerror = false;
}

if (captcha == "")
{
 var x = document.getElementsByClassName("error");
 x[4].innerHTML = "The captcha field is a required field.";
 messageerror = true;
}
else if (captcha != "")
{
 if (captcha != session)
 {
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("error");
  x[4].innerHTML = "Captcha mismatch.";
  messageerror = true;
 }
 else
 {
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("error");
  x[4].innerHTML = "";
  messageerror = false;
 }
}
if (nameerror == true || emailerror == true || subjecterror == true || messageerror == true || captcha == true)
{
 return false;
}
else
{
 return true;
}
 }
</script>
```

My form is as follows:

```
<form id="ContactForm" name="ContactForm" action="javascript:loadDoc();" onsubmit="return(validate());">
 <label for="Fullname">Name <span class="red">*</span><span class="error"></span></label>
 <input id="ContactFormInput" name="Fullname" class="text" id="Fullname">
 <label for="Emailadd">Email <span class="red">*</span><span class="error"></span></label>
 <input id="ContactFormInput" name="Emailadd" class="text" id="Emailadd">
 <label for="Subject">Subject <span class="red">*</span><span class="error"></span></label>
 <input id="ContactFormInput" name="Subject" class="text" id="Subject">
 <label for="Message">Message <span class="red">*</span><span class="error"> </span></label>
 <textarea id="Message" name="Message" rows="6" cols="30"></textarea>
<label for="CaptchaText" id="captchalabel">Captcha <span class="red">*</span><span class="error"></span></label>
<div id="CaptchaParent">
<div id="CaptchaIframe">
<img src="/Includes/captcha.php" id="captcha" />
</div><div id="CaptchaReload">
<img class="captchareload" src="/Images/Contact_Us/reload_icon.png" onclick="document.getElementById('captcha').src='/Includes/captcha.php?'+Math.random()">
</div><div id="CaptchaInput">
<input name="CaptchaText" id="CaptchaText" maxlength="8" class="text">
</div>
</div>
<div id="ContactInput">
<input id="Submit" class="ContactButton" type="submit" name="submit" class="button" value="Send Now"/>
</div>
</form>
```

My php session page has

```
<?php
session_start();

echo $_SESSION['captcha'];
?>
```

Comment: I'm not clear as to why you're calling `getcaptchsession()` in your `validate` function

Comment: Hi there, Originally I had the ajax line inside the  validate() function with the async flag set to false but I have been trying different methods to retrieve a result which was not undefined. Hope this makes sense. thanks Callum

Comment: You need to remove the `getcaptchsession` from the `validate` function and `onsubmit` call `getcaptchsession`. You may however need to cancel the submit and wait until validate finishes and then submit.

Comment: Hi there, Thanks for putting me on the right track. I removed the getcaptchasession() function from my validate() function and added a return false; to my getcaptchasession() function which stopped the first function from submitting the form until the second function had completed. Thanks once again Callum